# Python AppEngine, how to take parameters to another page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In my app, each page is each Python class. From page A, I want to take some data in this page and `redirect` to page B.

Does Google App Engine has some ways to do it ? (I don't want to use something like: global variable or cookie for this small work)

Thanks :)

Comment: Please explain further what you want to achieve. There are several ways to accomplish the same: cookies, GET parameters, memcache, datastore, etc. And by the way, there's no such thing as global variables, since GAE might run your code in several different instances.

Comment: @skreft oh. I don't know that, because don't try it before (global variables) And my need is GET Parameter

Comment: Are you using any specific framework like webapp or webapp2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the value you need in the first handler (AHandler), then redirect to the second handler (BHandler) passing that value as a GET parameter. Finally BHandler, reads that parameter and does something with it. Here is some code:

```
import urllib

class AHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    name = 'Some name'
    redirect('b?%s' % urllib.urlencode({'name': name}))

class BHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    # do something with name
```